# rails form - 2 fields with same id in a form - how to disable second field when first field is selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have in my rails form the following code:

```
<label>Fruit: </label>  <%= f.select(:IST_FRUIT, [['Apple', 'Apple'],
                          ['Orange', 'Orange'],
                          ['Kiwi', 'Kiwi'],
                          ['Other', 'Other']
                          ],{ :prompt => "Please select"},{:onchange => "if (this.value == 'Other') 
                                                                         {document.getElementById('otherTissue').style.display = 'block';
                                                                         } "}
                          ) %>

<span id="otherFruit" style="display:none;"> If other, please state: <%= f.text_field :IST_FRUIT, :size => 10  %></span>
```

User can select a fruit form the listbox but if user selects 'Other', a textfield is diaplayed allowing user to input his value.

The problem is that when user selects a fruit and save the form, the fruit field in blank in the table and the reason is that the form is saving the second field 'IST_FRUIT' found in the span with id 'IST_FRUIT'.

I would be really grateful if someone could show me a way how to disable the second field when 'other' is not selected and enable it when 'Other' is selected from the dropdown list.

Many many thanks for any suggestion provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be aware that rails posts are based on fields' name, not ids.

In your case, you should use a `virtual attribute` to store the potential `other fruit` value.

Your model could look like:

```
attr_accessor :other_fruit

before_save :check_fruits

def check_fruits
  #if other_fruit is not nil, it means that you want to store it's value in you IST_FRUIT column 
  #BTW, why these capital letters?
  IST_FRUIT = other_fruit unless other_fruit.nil?
end
```

And your form would be:

```
<span id="otherFruit" style="display:none;"> If other, please state: <%= f.text_field :other_fruit, :size => 10  %></span>
```

Comment: Hello,thanks a lot for the suggestion. I put 'def check_fruits' function in my fruit model and now am getting an error with the following line of code 'IST_FRUIT = other_fruit unless other_fruit.nil? - it's saying dynamic constant assigment error
'

Comment: what's the name of your `table`? Is this `IST_FRUIT` or more likely `ist_fruits`?

Comment: Got it - changed 'IST_FRUIT = other_fruit unless other_fruit.nil?
' to 'self[:IST_FRUIT]  = other_fruit unless other_fruit.blank?

Answer (score 1):

I have another advice. Instead of disabling a HTML input (by the way - an ID must be unique in a HTML document) just make another attribute in your model, name it 'other_fruit' for example, and use this value if the 'fruit' is set to 'other' or is empty. For example you may write something like this:

```
class TheModel
  attr :other_fruit

  # Overwritten accessor for the fruit attribute.
  # Returns the values of :other_fruit if :fruit is blank.
  #
  def fruit
    if self[:fruit].blank?
      other_fruit
    else
      self[:fruit]
    end
  end
end
```

Now the HTML part. In your JavaScript you set 'display' to block, but you do not reset it when user selects another option.

If you want to prevent the field from being sent to the server, you should set the 'disabled' attribute. Setting the 'style' only hides the control from the user's eyes.